# Generating warnings for Int32 to Int64 casts

Tags: c#, casting, compiler-warnings, static-analysis

Is there a way to generate compile time warnings for implicit `int` to `long` conversions? (An answer that involves a static analysis tool such as FxCop would be fine.)

Casting an `int` to a `long` is obviously a safe operation, but say we have a library that used to have `int` values for its identifiers and which is now upgraded to use `long` values for all of them.

Now, the client code needs to be updated accordingly. Because if the client is supplying an `Int32` argument to a method that expects `Int64` - it is very possible that the client code needs to be updated.

An example scenario would be the following:

```
private void OnProcessGizmoClick()
{
    int gizmoId = 2;

    // I want the following usage to generate warnings:
    GizmoFactoryInstance.ProcessGizmo(gizmoId);
}

// Library code
public void ProcessGizmo(long gizmoId);
```

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae The main concern here is how to generate warnings. It won't break it. He knows that. What he wants is for him to be prompted if ever an implicit cast is present in his code.

Comment: find all usages of  `GizmoFactoryInstance.ProcessGizmo`, the legacy code must necessarily use `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your own type with implicit conversion from both `long` and `int`; make warning on implicit conversion from `int` like:

```
public struct GizmoInteger
{
  private long m_Value;
  private GizmoInteger(long value)
  {
    m_Value = value;
  }

  [Obsolete("Use long instead")]
  public static implicit operator GizmoInteger(int value)
  {
    return new GizmoInteger(value);
  }

  public static implicit operator GizmoInteger(long value)
  {
    return new GizmoInteger(value);
  }
}

void Foo(GizmoInteger i)
{
}

// warning
Foo(4);
// OK
Foo(4L);
```

Comment: I ended up writing my own FxCop rule (and still had to do a lot of additional text searching and eyeballing) but I just accepted this one. It would probably be the safest option if I used it from the start.

Comment: Could you post this FxCop rule? :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think that the best way would be to overload the method with an Int32 parameter input, which internally could just perform the cast to Int64 - but your overloaded method could be marked as Deprecated.

```
[Obsolete("Please use an Int64 for your identifier instead")]
```

Then Visual Studio will see both versions, and use the Int32 declaration which would give a deprecated warning.

If in a later release, or for certain methods that you absolutely don't want to be called with the Int32 parameter you were to decide that you wanted to cause a compiler error, you could also update it to the following.

```
[Obsolete("Please use an Int64 for your identifier instead", true)]
```

Comment: Certainly a good idea for methods. Unfortunately the library also exposes properties, and overloading won't help with those. I'd have to go ahead and break the whole thing by renaming the properties. I hope it won't have to come to that.